# What changes with Kerberos Authentication in IPv6 when using NAT?

Tags: ipv6, kerberos, mitkerberos

How should Kerberos Authentication be setup with IPv6?

Of you're using NAT for IPv6 where there is a single public IPv6 address and it translates to the machines inside in the ULA range?

Comment: This is NOT the same as the other one.  The other one specifies not using NAT and this one specifies using NAT.  Or are you saying that the answer is already in the other question?

Comment: Well, first off, you're not going to use NAT with IPv6. So the question as-is is kind of pointless. Since you aren't going to use NAT with IPv6, you're left with the other answer.

Comment: NAT exists for IPv6, therefore it is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, it exists, but you'd have to be crazy to use it. NPTv6 is somewhat better, but even that should be avoided whenever possible. See [RFC 6296 section 5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6296#section-5) for the implications.